# I'm making a website in which you need to enter a four-digit password to go to the next page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a beginner at coding, I'm making a website in which you need to enter a four-digit password to go to the next page.

I have a form which is where you fill in the code, and then a button which when pressed with either if the code is right redirect the user to a different page or if wrong send the user an error message But It's not working and I don't know why. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Login Form</title>


      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>
<body>

  <html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script  src="js/script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700">

</head>
    <div id="login">
      <form name='form-login'>
        <span class="fontawesome-lock"></span>
          <input type="password" name="password" maxlength="4" class="span7" id="pass" placeholder="Password" required/>

<button type="submit" id="submit" onclick="onSubmit()">Sign In</button>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
@import url(http://weloveiconfonts.com/api/?family=fontawesome);

[class*="fontawesome-"]:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: #2c3338;
  color: #606468;
  font: 87.5%/1.5em 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

input {
  border: none;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

p {
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

after { clear: both; }

#login {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 320px;
}

#login form {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 22px 22px 22px 22px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #282e33;
  border-top: 3px solid #434a52;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #434a52;
}

#login form span {
  background-color: #363b41;
  border-radius: 3px 0px 0px 3px;
  border-right: 3px solid #434a52;
  color: #606468;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

#login form input[type="text"] {
  background-color: #3b4148;
  border-radius: 0px 3px 3px 0px;
  color: #a9a9a9;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding: 0 16px;
  width: 235px;
  height: 50px;
}

#login form input[type="password"] {
  background-color: #3b4148;
  border-radius: 0px 3px 3px 0px;
  color: #a9a9a9;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding: 0 16px;
  width: 235px;
  height: 50px;
}

#login form input[type="submit"] {
  background: #b5cd60;
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
#login form input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #16aa56;
}

button{
        background: #1ab188;
        border: 0;
        color: white;
        border-radius: 3px;
        height: 40px;
        width: 100%;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 16px;
        transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

JS:

```
function onSubmit() {

         if (document.getElementById('password').value == '1234') {location.replace("https://www.w3schools.com") }else{ alert('Access Denied, Please try again');}`enter code here`
     }
```

Comment: [tag:java] question tag removed and [tag:javascript] tag added. Please be careful with your tagging because correct tagging is critical to getting the right experts to your question, and this question has absolutely nothing to do with Java programming. Also, can you tell what debugging you've done and then use this to help make your question much more specific?

Comment: You need to only use one <head> area. before <body>

Comment: Your input element has the id pass not password.

Comment: Javascript is client side, and anyone can simply do Ctrl + U to see that the necessary password is 1234. I suggest using a serverside language like php or python

Comment: Not to mention this does nothing to protect user opening the other url themselves in address bar and bypass entering any password. Client side only authorization is virtually useless

Comment: Downvoted for hostile rollback. Please accept good edits to your questions, and refrain from adding chatty or begging material to your posts.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few issues with your code:

1. When you use `type="submit"` on a button your page will refresh every time you click that button as it is trying to submit the form data. This means that you won't see your javascript doing anything. In your case, you don't need to submit the form, and so you can change `type="submit"` to `type="button"` on your button.
2. Your not getting the password correctly. At the moment you are trying to get the password from an element with the `id` password. However, your HTML doesn't have an element with the id `password`. Instead, you need to use `pass` as the id:

   `document.getElementById('pass').value`

Fixing these issues should fix your problem. However, if you're using this system for something important I would not recommend it. Anyone can easily see the password your using through developer tools. Instead, I would recommend using a server-side language to handle this (eg NodeJS or PHP).

See working example below:

```js
function onSubmit() {
  if (document.getElementById('pass').value == '1234') {
    window.location.href = "https://www.w3schools.com";
  } else {
    alert('Access Denied, Please try again');
  }
}
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
@import url(http://weloveiconfonts.com/api/?family=fontawesome);
[class*="fontawesome-"]:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: #2c3338;
  color: #606468;
  font: 87.5%/1.5em 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

input {
  border: none;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

p {
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

after {
  clear: both;
}

#login {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 320px;
}

#login form {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 22px 22px 22px 22px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #282e33;
  border-top: 3px solid #434a52;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #434a52;
}

#login form span {
  background-color: #363b41;
  border-radius: 3px 0px 0px 3px;
  border-right: 3px solid #434a52;
  color: #606468;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

#login form input[type="text"] {
  background-color: #3b4148;
  border-radius: 0px 3px 3px 0px;
  color: #a9a9a9;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding: 0 16px;
  width: 235px;
  height: 50px;
}

#login form input[type="password"] {
  background-color: #3b4148;
  border-radius: 0px 3px 3px 0px;
  color: #a9a9a9;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding: 0 16px;
  width: 235px;
  height: 50px;
}

#login form input[type="submit"] {
  background: #b5cd60;
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#login form input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #16aa56;
}

button {
  background: #1ab188;
  border: 0;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="login">
  <form name='form-login'>
    <span class="fontawesome-lock"></span>
    <input type="password" name="password" maxlength="4" class="span7" id="pass" placeholder="Password" required/>

    <button type="button" id="submit" onclick="onSubmit()">Sign In</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried putting this into Brackets the software and It does the same thing of reloading.

Comment: @Parzival did you change both the HTML and Javascript?

Comment: This is the Java Script:function onSubmit() {

  if (document.getElementById('pass').value == '1234') {
    location.replace("https://www.w3schools.com")
  } else {
    alert('Access Denied, Please try again');
  }
}

Comment: @Parzival did you remove `type="submit"` on the button?

Comment: In HTML? I just copy and pasted what you wrote.

Comment: @Parzival yeah, in the HTML. The code snippet is working here so I'm not sure why it wouldn't be working on your side

Comment: @Parzival I've made one small change to my code, maybe see if it works now

Comment: Now nothing happens.

Comment: @Parzival can you please make a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla) replicating your issue

Comment: To simply remove `type="submit"` from the `button` is not gonna prevent it from submitting, and the reason is that that is the default.

Comment: @LGSon hm, that's what I originally thought, but when I removed `type="submit"` from the button in the code snippet the submission didn't seem to occur, making me think that it wasn't actually the button but rather `type="submit"` doing it. I've modified my answer now though

Comment: It does submit, and to prevent it, don't use `preventDefault()`, simply change its `type` to `button`, e.g. `<button type="button">` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Answer (score 0):

I left the css untouched. Nick Parsons pointed out the main issues. In my solution, I changed the JavaScript to match what you have defined the id for the password input to be.

There's also some issues with your HTML, so I'm putting the HTML and JavaScript files here as well.

```
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="login">
      <form name='form-login' onsubmit="event.preventDefault()">
        <span class="fontawesome-lock"></span>
        <input type="password" name="password" maxlength="4" class="span7" id="password" placeholder="Password" required/>
        <button type="submit" id="submit" onclick="onSubmit()">Sign In</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here's your new js/script.js:

```
function onSubmit() {
  if (document.getElementById('password').value == '1234') {
    console.log('bingo');
    window.location.replace("https://www.w3schools.com");
  } else{
    alert('Access Denied, Please try again');
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Now nothing happens.